# GC overhead limit exceeded in Sparkjob with join

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-2.0

I am writing a spark job to get the latest student records filtered by the student date. But when I try this with hundred thousand of records it is working fine. But when I run it with large number of records my sparkjob returns below error.

I guess this error happens since I load all the data from the table and put int in a RDD. Because my table contains about 4.2 millions of records. If that is so, is there any better way to efficiently load those data and continue my operation successfully ?

Please anybody help me to resolve this

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1, 10.10.10.10): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRowFast(MysqlIO.java:2157)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.nextRow(MysqlIO.java:1964)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readSingleRowSet(MysqlIO.java:3316)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.getResultSet(MysqlIO.java:463)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readResultsForQueryOrUpdate(MysqlIO.java:3040)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readAllResults(MysqlIO.java:2288)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2681)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2551)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1861)
at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1962)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$$anon$1.<init>(JDBCRDD.scala:408)
at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD.compute(JDBCRDD.scala:379)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:332)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$8.apply(RDD.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:935)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:866)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:926)
at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:670)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:281)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:319)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:283)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)

17/03/09 10:54:09 INFO TaskSetManager: Starting task 0.1 in stage    1.0 (TID 2, 10.10.10.10, partition 0, PROCESS_LOCAL, 5288 bytes)
17/03/09 10:54:09 INFO CoarseGrainedSchedulerBackend$DriverEndpoint:   Launching task 2 on executor id: 1 hostname: 10.10.10.10.
17/03/09 10:54:09 WARN TransportChannelHandler: Exception in connection from /10.10.10.10:48464
java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer
at sun.nio.ch.FileDispatcherImpl.read0(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:39)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:313)
at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:881)
at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.    java:242)
at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNio    ByteChannel.java:119)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:511)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoo    p.java:468)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:38    2)
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:354)
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$2.run(SingleThreadEvent    Executor.java:111)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
17/03/09 10:54:09 ERROR TaskSchedulerImpl: Lost executor 1 on     10.10.10.10: Remote RPC client disassociated. Likely due to containers     exceeding thresholds, or network issues. Check driver logs for WARN     messages.
17/03/09 10:54:09 INFO StandaloneAppClient$ClientEndpoint: Executor     updated: app-20170309105209-0032/1 is now EXITED (Command exited with code     52)
```

Code

```
object StudentDataPerformanceEnhancerImpl extends studentDataPerformanceEnhancer {
    val LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass.getName)
    val USER_PRIMARY_KEY = "user_id";
    val COURSE_PRIMARY_KEY = "course_id";

    override def extractData(sparkContext: SparkContext, sparkSession:    SparkSession, jobConfiguration: JobConfiguration): Unit = {
        val context = sparkSession.read.format("jdbc")
        .option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver")
        .option("url", jobConfiguration.jdbcURL)
        .option("dbtable", "student_student")
        .option("user", test_user)
        .option("password", test_password)
        .load()
        context.cache()

        val mainRDD = context.rdd.map(k => ((k.getLong(k.fieldIndex(USER_PRIMARY_KEY)),
            k.getLong(k.fieldIndex(COURSE_PRIMARY_KEY)),
            k.getTimestamp(k.fieldIndex("student_date_time"))),
            (k.getLong(k.fieldIndex(USER_PRIMARY_KEY)),
                k.getLong(k.fieldIndex(COURSE_PRIMARY_KEY)),
                k.getTimestamp(k.fieldIndex("student_date_time")),
                k.getString(k.fieldIndex("student_student_index")),
                k.getLong(k.fieldIndex("student_category_pk")),
                k.getString(k.fieldIndex("effeciency")),
                k.getString(k.fieldIndex("net_score")),
                k.getString(k.fieldIndex("avg_score")),
                k.getString(k.fieldIndex("test_score"))))).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)

        LOG.info("Data extractions started....!")
        try {
            val studentCompositeRDD = context.rdd.map(r => ((r.getLong(r.fieldIndex(USER_PRIMARY_KEY)),
            r.getLong(r.fieldIndex(COURSE_PRIMARY_KEY))),
            r.getTimestamp(r.fieldIndex("student_date_time")))).reduceByKey((t1, t2) => if (t1.after(t2)) t1 else t2)
                .map(t => ((t._1._1, t._1._2, t._2), t._2)).persist(StorageLevel.DISK_ONLY)
            val filteredRDD = mainRDD.join(studentCompositeRDD).map(k => k._2._1)
            DataWriter.persistLatestData(filteredRDD)
        } catch {
            case e: Exception => LOG.error("Error in spark job: " + e.getMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

My DataWriter class related to database persistence is below

```
object DataWriter {
    def persistLatestStudentRiskData(rDD: RDD[(Long, Long, Timestamp, String,    Long, String, String, String, String)]): Unit = {
        var jdbcConnection: java.sql.Connection = null
        try {
            jdbcConnection = DatabaseUtil.getConnection
            if (jdbcConnection != null) {
                val statement = "{call insert_latest_student_risk    (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}"
                val callableStatement = jdbcConnection.prepareCall(statement)

                rDD.collect().foreach(x => sendLatestStudentRiskData(callableStatement, x))
            }
        } catch {
            case e: SQLException => LOG.error("Error in executing insert_latest_student_risk stored procedure : " + e.getMessage)
            case e: RuntimeException => LOG.error("Error in the latest student persistence: " + e.getMessage)
            case e: Exception => LOG.error("Error in the latest student persistence: " + e.getMessage)
        } finally {
            if (jdbcConnection != null) {
                try {
                    jdbcConnection.close()
                } catch {
                    case e: SQLException => LOG.error("Error in jdbc connection close : " + e.getMessage)
                    case e: Exception => LOG.error("Error in executing insert_latest_student_risk stored procedure : " + e.getMessage)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    def sendLatestStudentRiskData(callableStatement: java.sql.CallableStatement,
        latestStudentData: (Long, Long, Timestamp,   String, Long,
    String, String, String, String)): Unit = {
        try {
            callableStatement.setLong(1, latestStudentData._1)
            callableStatement.setLong(2, latestStudentData._2)
            callableStatement.setTimestamp(3, latestStudentData._3)
            callableStatement.setString(4, latestStudentData._4)
            callableStatement.setLong(5, latestStudentData._5)
            callableStatement.setString(6, latestStudentData._6)
            callableStatement.setString(7, latestStudentData._7)
            callableStatement.setString(8, latestStudentData._8)
            callableStatement.setString(9, latestStudentData._9)

            callableStatement.executeUpdate
        } catch {
            case e: SQLException => LOG.error("Error in executing insert_latest_student_risk stored procedure : " + e.getMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is `DataWriter.persistLatestData` defined?

Comment: @puhlen I updated the question with DataWriter.persistLatestData

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you are putting data into the RDD, is that you are taking the data out of the RDD and onto the driver memory.  Specifically, the problem is the `collect` call you are using to persist the data. You should remove it.  `collect` brings the entire RDD into memory on the driver and you are no longer using spark and your cluster to process data so you quickly run out of memory unless your data size is very small.  `collect` should rarely be used by spark processes, it's mostly useful for development and debugging with small amounts of data.  It has some uses in production applications for some supporting operations but not as a main data flow.

Spark is able to write to jdbc directly if you use spark-sql, leverage that and remove calls to collect.